# Are there examples of counterfeit studies?

Tags: publications

At the best of your knowledge are there any examples of faked studies published on journals and then turned out to be manipulated?

Comment: Just googling "Fake Scientific Studies" quickly leads to [this list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_misconduct#Notable_individual_cases), which includes what you're describing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the answer is easy to find with a search engine or on Wikipedia. I don't believe that it is off-topic (even if the SE interface is going to display  that I voted to close it as off-topic).

Comment: Thank's for no real support showed to this question even though the answer could be pretty simple and fast. I found it myself. You can delete it if you want now. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are, and for some of those it's pretty obvious.

Retraction watch is pretty good for this. [Here's an article about a fake chemistry study where you can see the bad paint copy-paste pretty easily](http://retractionwatch.com/2013/08/16/nano-letters-retracts-chopstick-nanorod-paper-questioned-this-week-on-chemistry-blogs/). And that's a quite high-impact journals. Reviewers completly failed on that one.

Comment: There are also ways to counterfait a study in the part of statistical analysis? 
For example: the only way to legitimately counterfait statistical results is to alter them yourself by changing values?

Comment: I see a contradiction there between legitimately and counterfeit.